# Hertz vs. Frequency

Tags: frequency

What is the difference between hertz and frequency? I'm having a debate with some friends. I say they're the same thing. They say I'm using the wrong terminology.

Comment: It is the same differences as Celcius and Temperature.  You ought to study harder.

Comment: So essentially no difference? Thanks for the opinion.

Comment: @KJason what?? There's a whole world of difference between "Celsius" and "Temperature"! You **really** should be studying harder. Or at least read two wikipedia articles (Frequency and Hertz) and the obviously linked "Unit" article.

Comment: @KJason , where did you go (or are you going) to school?..

Comment: Sorry, i thought i read celcius and farenhieght. I read it too quickly. Sorry.

Comment: The frequency these questions appear Hertz my brain

Comment: I would argue that in some informal/conversational circumstances they can be somewhat substituted; "what the hertz -vs- what's the frequency?", to which "50" is apt for both...

Comment: @dandavis  I'm sure a lot of analog engineers exclaim "what the hertz?!" when they see their amplifier oscillating.

Comment: @NickAlexeev: heh, got a chuckle out of that missing `'s`...

Comment: Hertz is an SI [derived **unit**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_derived_unit#Derived_units_with_special_names) exactly equivalent to \$s^{-1}\$ (seconds being the base unit). Frequency is a **quantity** you can measure in **units** of Hz.

Answer (score 17):

Your friends are right.

"Frequency" is a property of anything that happens periodically;

"Hertz" is just a unit of measure for frequency.

Think of "length" vs "meter": not even remotely the same thing.

This is pretty basic; if you're at a point where you're discussing frequency, you should also be able to understand the difference between property and unit.

Answer (score 2):

As Marcus Miller answered, frequency is a property, and Hertz is a unit of measurement used to specify frequency.

Let's take a sound wave which cycles from positive pressure to negative pressure and back to positive 1000 times per second. That cycle rate is the sound frequency. Ordinarily, you would say that the frequency is 1000 Hz, or 1 kHz. However, you could just as well say that the frequency is 60,000 cycles per minute. Or 3,600,000 cycles per hour. There is no absolute requirement to express frequency in Hz, although that is the accepted unit used by virtually all scientists and engineers these days, and to use another unit is likely to draw criticism.

Comment: "I listen to The Radio Morning Show on my way to work every day on 6Grpm" yeah, other units are unusual in signal processing and physics, but for people that design motors, rpm might be a useful unit, and for geologists maybe "per century" is one, who knows :) anyway, have an upvote

Answer (score 0):

Frequency is the periodicity of the time series that maximally correlates with the signal.

Centuries ago that periodicity was named "cycles per second".

In the 1960s, CPS was coerced into Hertz.

Comment: The post about temperature was the best in this one. It being the same difference between temperature and celcius.

Comment: But i also liked the cycles per second. A little something from history and i also just like the concept cycles per second, or maybe cycles per time, as the words seem more to the heart of the matter than frequency.